# RaspBerry PI beacon bluetooth C#

Tags: c#, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon

Hello i'm working on a little project and a part of it should be my raspberry pi acting as a beacon, then i should send him some data with an Android app but it's my first time working with this and i don't know how to set this up.
I found this code from the windows Beacon Library, but how do i include the library in my project? When i try to search it with the NuGet packets i can't find it

```
using Altbeacon;
using Altbeacon.Beacon;
BeaconTransmitter = new BeaconTransmitter(new BeaconParser().SetBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EddystoneUidLayout));
            List<long> dataFields = new List<long>();
            dataFields.Add(0);
            Beacon beacon = new Beacon.Builder()
                .SetTxPower(-59).SetDataFields(dataFields)
                .SetId1("0x00112233445566778899")
                .SetId2("0xAABBCCDDEEFF").Build();
            BeaconTransmitter.StartAdvertising(beacon);
```

Comment: Is it this one? https://github.com/AltBeacon/windows-beacon-library

Just looking at it it says in the readme that you'll need to clone and compile it yourself (no published nuget package), then you'll be able to reference it in your project